# Недостаточен объем памяти для выполнения программы

Tags: qt, c++

Очень огромное изображение обрабатывается 5 раз. Каждый раз вызывается обработчик AddNoiseHandler::startHandler(), где используется одно и тоже исходное изображение. Результат добавляется в стек. После 4-го раза приложение занимает за 1000 мб оперативной памяти. На 5-ом вылет происходит в строке: uchar* line = result->scanLine(i);

```
void AddNoiseHandler::startHandler()
{
    // Добавление шума
    // Формула: C' = C + (Noise * 255 - 127)
    // C'- новый цвет
    // C - старый цвет

    try {
        emit setStatus(2);
        emit setPercent(0);

        std::shared_ptr<QImage> intelligent_picture(new QImage(*source));

        if (intelligent_picture->isNull()) {
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();
        }

        result = intelligent_picture;

        register int level = levelNoise;
        register int step = result->height() / 100;

        register int width = result->width() * 4;
        register int height = result->height();

        QMessageBox msg;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {

            // При недостатке ОП здесь вылет
            uchar* line = result->scanLine(i);

            // r, g, b, a
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j += 4) {

                register int r = line[j];     // Red
                register int g = line[j + 1]; // Green
                register int b = line[j + 2]; // Blue

                r = r + (int)(level * 255.0 / 100.0 - 127.0);
                r > 255? r = 255 : 0;
                r < 0? r = 0 : 0;

                g = g + (int)(level * 255.0 / 100.0 - 127.0);
                g > 255? g = 255 : 0;
                g < 0? g = 0 : 0;

                b = b + (int)(level * 255.0 / 100.0 - 127.0);
                b > 255? b = 255 : 0;
                b < 0? b = 0 : 0;

                line[j] = r;
                line[j + 1] = g;
                line[j + 2] = b;
            }

            if (i % step == 0)
            {
                emit setPercent(i / step);
            }
        }

        emit setPercent(100);
        emit setStatus(5);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryException* error) {
        emit setStatus(3);
        emit sendError(error);
    }
}
```

Как предотвратить вылет?

Comment: Стойте, вы говорите, что результаты _добавляются в стек_? То есть, у вас в памяти должно оказаться 5 немного изменённых копий _очень огромного_ изображения? Ну тогда памяти и правда может не хватить, что ж вы думали. Не храните все 5 копий изображения в памяти, делов-то! Храните только те, которые вам нужны.

Comment: а насколько "очень громное изображение"?

Comment: нужно хранить все изображения, а при недостатке памяти выдать сообщение. Утечки памяти нет. Использую shared_ptr. При обычном изображении работает нормально. Но когда берется изображение 8192x5460 на жестком диске занимает 50 мб. В оперативной памяти в обёртке QImage 170 мб. Таким образом, во время выполнения имеется 2 одинаковых исходных изображений (так нужно, никак не изменить), и за каждую обработку появляется новое, но с разным шумом. Таких я могу сделать 4 шт. Считаем: 20мб само приложение + (2 + 4) * 170 мб = 1040 мб. При следующей обработке вылет. Предел по количеству изображений 20 ш

Comment: @vaddemgen: 1) А точно ли нужно хранить все в памяти? Почему бы уже готовые временно не вытеснить на диск?

2) Я думаю, проблема на самом деле в [implicit data sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html#implicit-data-sharing). Вы не делаете настоящую копию картинки, внутри у картинки указатель на общие данные с оригиналом. При первой попытке доступа к пикселям (`scanLine()`) происходит попытка клонирования данных, которая и падает из-за нехватки памяти.

Попробуйте вызвать `detach()` сразу после «копирования».

Comment: @vaddemgen: Если `detach()` недоступен, попробуйте вызвать `bits()` (оно вызовет точно `detach()` внутри) и проверьте результат на 0. Это, кажется, валидный метод проверки на переполнение.

Comment: @vaddemgen: а с `bits` работает? В любом случае, это подтверждает то, что проблема с data sharing.

Comment: @vaddemgen: Хм. Попробуйте тогда не делать копию в «автоматическом» режиме, а вручную: создайте «чистую» картинку нужного размера при помощи [`QImage::create()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qimage-qt3.html#create) и скопируйте в неё данные из картинки-оригинала через `bits()` и (например) `memcpy`.

---
P.S.: У вас вышел лимит комментариев, удаляйте старые.

Comment: @vaddemgen: Или создайте пустой `QImage` нужного размера при помощи [конструктора с размером](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-3) и проверьте результат на [`isNull`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#isNull).

Comment: @VladD Отлично! Получилось! Вот что сделал:
try {
//...
uchar* dataSrc = this->source->bits();
uchar* dataDst = new uchar[length]; // Здесь при недостатке памяти вылет
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  dataDst[i] = dataSrc[i];
}

std::shared_ptr<QImage> intelligent_picture(new QImage(dataDst, width, height, source->format()));
} catch (std::bad_alloc&) { /* ... */}

Comment: @vaddemgen: отлично! перенесу в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, проблема на самом деле в [implicit data sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html#implicit-data-sharing). Вы не делаете настоящую копию картинки, внутри у картинки указатель на общие данные с оригиналом. При первой попытке доступа к пикселям (`scanLine()`) происходит попытка клонирования данных, которая и падает из-за нехватки памяти.

Вам нужно вызывать конструктор, который проверяют размер самостоятельно, а не пользуется (удобным) неявным копированием. Например, создайте «чистую» картинку нужного размера при помощи [`QImage::create()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qimage-qt3.html#create) и скопируйте в неё данные из картинки-оригинала через `bits()` и (например) `memcpy`. Или при помощи [конструктора с размером](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-3) и проверьте результат на [`isNull`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#isNull).

---

Update: На самом деле вам не надо самому создавать данные, доверьтесь конструктору `QImage`. Например, что-то такое должно сработать:

```
std::shared_ptr<QImage> intelligent_picture(new QImage(width, height, format));

if (intelligent_picture->isNull())
{
    // значит, памяти не хватило, ругаемся и выходим
}

// если мы тут, памяти хватает
// копируем данные
uchar* dataSrc = this->source->bits();
uchar* dataDst = intelligent_picture->bits();
memcpy(dataDst, dataSrc, length * sizeof(uchar));
```

Обошлись без исключений.

Comment: @vaddemgen: обновил ответ